# string inside Text View doen't be animated, i don't know why it works like that

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to animate Text view in SwiftUI, but string inside it doen't be animted. I don't know why and need some help.

I'm making ios application showing location detail. It is fetched by async function(`loadData`). and when fetch is finished, i want to show this with animation which makes `Text("Loading")` move away and fade in and `Text(data == nil ? "" : representiveName!)` move to intended spot and fade out.
but when data is fetched red border from second `Text` is moving top to down but string in `Text` doen't move, it is just located at intended spot from beginig and fades out. help me please

```
    ZStack {
        Text("Loading")
            .offset(CGSize(width: 0, height: data == nil ? 0:50))
            .opacity(data == nil ? 1:0)
        Text(data == nil ? "" : representiveName!)
            .border(.red)
            .offset(CGSize(width: 0, height: data == nil ? -50:0))
            .opacity(data == nil ? 0:1)
    }
    .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.5).delay(0.5), value: data)            
    .task {
        data = await loadData(logitude: longitude, latitude: latitude)
    }
```

Comment: You have to apply .animation to each text and remove it from ZStack.

Answer (score 0):

I think to make the text inside the Text view animate as you want, you should use the `.animation` modifier correctly and make sure to wrap the content you want to animate inside a withAnimation block.

```
struct ContentView: View {
        @State private var data: String? = nil // Replace with your actual data type
    
        private let representiveName = "Your Location Data" // Replace with your actual data
    
        var body: some View {
                    ZStack {
                        // "Loading" text with animation
                        if data == nil {
                            Text("Loading")
                                .offset(y: -50)
                                .opacity(1)
                                .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.5).delay(0.5))
                        }
            
                        // Text with location data and animation
                        if let locationData = data {
                            Text(locationData)
                                .border(.red)
                                .offset(y: 0)
                                .opacity(1)
                                .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.5).delay(0.5))
                        }
                    }
                    .onAppear {
                        loadDataAndAnimate()
                    }
                }
            
                func loadDataAndAnimate() {
                    // Simulate data loading delay
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
                        data = representiveName
                    }
                } 
 }
```